# Which are the basic steps to make a dual boot computer single boot?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, arch-linux

I'm asking for guidelines to configure my dual-boot computer (Windows 10, Arch linux) to just boot to Arch. I want to do this because i installed Windows as a requirement to some courses in school but i believe i will no longer need it. What annoys me the most is that Windows won't let Linux to be the default booting OS.

What steps or things in general should i keep in mind while doing this? I felt, when i set the dual boot, that i did things in a sloppy way and i wish to do things right this time. This is my computer http://support.hp.com/es-es/product/HP-Pavilion-14-Sleekbook/5375393/model/5403360/document/c03819815/

Comment: Which grub you used? Grub or Grub Legacy/GRUB2 ?

Comment: 1. I'm guessing reinstalling is out of the question? Any dual boot system implies at least a minor mess with bootloaders and the partition layout. It can be fixed, of course, but it can be difficult and/or dangerous, especially for inexperienced users. So, IMHO, you are going to need a backup anyway. 2. Ouf of curiosity, why did you dual-boot instead of installing Windows in e.g. a VirtualBox VM?

Comment: ariestiyansyah  i'm using refind because i read that it might help overriding windows as default OS. @thkala No, actually i was thinking in wiping my hd and reinstalling, but wanted help figuring out a safe, clean and correct way to set my pc with uefi. I believe that there are plenty of types of formatting options and concepts like ext, fat, partition tables, etc, that i'm unfamiliar with. I dual-booted because i was working with databases and internet and ports and i tought it would be less of a mess. Also, visual studio is heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` then Change the Grub timeout;

`GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` and/or hide Grub menu `GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU="true"`

restart the grub with command

`$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`